# THTTPClient close TCP connection after response (avoit TIME_WAIT connection)

Tags: delphi, tcp, httpclient, indy

i made some request to a backend endpoint, eg.:

```
var
   aClient: THTTPClient;
begin
   aClient := THTTPClient.Create;
   aClient.Get('https://example.com/api/foo');
   aClient.free;
end;
```

I have also tried to reuse the same HTTPClient istance...

After `aClient.free` the TCP connection stale in `TIME_WAIT` state for a while...

I want force Windows to immediately close the connection after the response, the first try is to add the header:

```
aClient.CustomHeaders['connection'] := 'close';
```

the second try is to edit the Delphi `System.Net.HttpClient.Win.pas` end add `DISABLE_KEEP_ALIVE` option

*System.Net.HttpClient.Win.pas (Line 839)*

```
OptionValue := WINHTTP_DISABLE_KEEP_ALIVE;
WinHttpSetOption(LRequest.FWRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_DISABLE_FEATURE, @OptionValue, sizeof(OptionValue));
```

both seem not have any effect..

I have also tried to use Indy client:

```
var
   aClient: TIdHTTP;
begin
   aClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
   aClient.Request.Connection := 'close';
   aClient.Get('https://example.com/api/foo');
   aClient.Disconnect(False);
   aClient.free;
end;
```

Comment: `TIME_WAIT` indicates that local endpoint has closed the connection. Here is described how TCP [connection termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination) works.

Comment: ok, but why windows take the TCP connection in this state and don't close immediately?

Comment: It is required by design of TCP protocol.

Comment: @zed `TIME_WAIT` indicates the local peer has closed its endpoint *FIRST*, sending `FIN` to the remote peer, and has received that peer's `FIN`. In this state, the local OS waits a little bit of time (the `TIME_WAIT` state) before releasing the local endpoint completely. Had the remote peer closed its endpoint *FIRST*, sending `FIN` after the response when `connection: close` is used, and the local peer had not closed its endpoint until after receiving the remote peer's `FIN`, then `TIME_WAIT` is avoided. See the [TCP state diagram](https://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/debugging-tcp.html)

Comment: But, why the OS take the connection in TIME_WAIT if the client close it with a dispose/free?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Windows take the TCP connection in TIME_WAIT for (less or more) 2 minutes... it's a lot of time... why this long time?

Comment: @ar099968 Did you read my link? It says: "After the side that sent the first FIN has responded with the final ACK, it waits for a timeout before finally closing the connection, during which time the local port is unavailable for new connections; `this prevents confusion due to delayed packets being delivered during subsequent connections`."

Comment: Yes @zeb, i have read. The point is: is "normal" 2 minutes for TIME_WAIT? or i need to investigate in my side why Windows wait for this long time?

Comment: 120 seconds is a default timeout value for `TIME_WAIT` on Windows. But, you can change it, setting `TcpTimedWaitDelay`: [Settings that can be Modified to Improve Network Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance)

Comment: zed, RemyLebeau thanks for the help!